# Button in slidingdrawer!

Tags: android

I'm having a button in a sliding drawer in a Android Application. The problem is it does not seem to react to any clicks as normal buttons do.

I'm guessing the problem is that it's a different view than buttons on the normal view.
If I implement a button the normal way like this

`myAgenda = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnMyAgenda);
        myAgenda.setOnClickListener(this);`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.BtnMyAgenda:
        test.setAnimation(leftLeft);
        test.startAnimation(leftLeft);
        break;
```

}

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the above code since the button is in a SlidingDrawer and not in the "normal" view.
Any ideas how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution to the problem, I simply created a new view.onclicklistener specific to that button.

`final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

```
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

Register with event listner like below code 
     button.setOnClickListener(clickButtonListener);

and create this listner for button

```
 private OnClickListener clickButtonListener= new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(v == button) 
        {
                     }
             }
     }
```